# Ridge regression combined with genetic data does not provide credible confidence intervals after bootstrapping

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have many regression problems (~14,000) that are highly multicollinear (genetic data), and I apply ridge regression to solve it, which produces  promising results in simulated data. My regression problem looks something like this:
$$
y = \mathbf{X} \beta + \epsilon
$$
Where $\mathbf{X}$ is really multicollinear, but fortunately my number of observations $n = 15,000$ is larger than my number of explanatory variables $m = 3,000$. All observations and all explanatory variables are standardized.

Currently, I'm using a test statistic as described by Cule et al. {1}, which is supposed to represent a p value of $\beta_j \neq 0$, but unfortunately, it does not follow a p value distribution in my simulated data, when I do not simulate an effect on  $\beta_j$.

I want to keep this test statistic, as it is very good at discriminating between an effect, and no effect (in other simulations, not shown). Below, I'm showing the observed p values, compared to the expectation in my null simulation, (~1,000 simulations).
[image: expected p values, compared to observed when no effect is simulated]

My goal is to transform  this test statistic into another statistic that has a p value distribution when there is no effect.

I've already tried multiple bootstrapping schemes, to obtain confidence intervals on $\beta_j$: bootstrapping the test statistic, bootstrapping the beta_coefficient. But this results in deflated and inflated false positives respectively. 
In addition, during bootstrapping, the variance of the distribution does not change much (< 1% difference after 50 bootstraps, compared to 1,000 bootstraps). So I'm reasonably confident that the underlying distribution is smooth.

I would like to have some suggestions on how I could approach the problem and find a test statistic that is p value distributed.

{1} https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-12-372

Comment: My suggestion is to try a permutation test (the authors use a test which is inspired from these) to see if they perform better. If permutation tests perform better ditch this test. Also your graph is confusing, not really sure what you are showing, usually you would show the p-value distribution. Also, how do you plan on `transforming this test statistic into another statistic`?

Comment: Thank you for this quick comment. I've changed the figure to contain Axis labels for clarity. In addition, I think transformation is not the correct formulation, so I will change this as well.

Comment: BTW why do you choose ridge regression versus L1 regularisation? IMO L1 is better for hierarchical data whilst L2 is better for 'equivalent' correlated data eg pixels. how would you describe your gene data?

Comment: My $\mathbf{X}$ matrix is comprised of three options (homozygote reference, heterozygotes, homozygote alternative alleles), which are standardized to mean 0 and variance 1. I prefer L2 regularization because I want to always have an estimate of certain $\beta_j$, in L1 regularization, more often that not, my j'th variable is regularized to 0.